# How to gain milliseconds of LocalTime variable?

Tags: java

Executed piece of code :

```
    String lapTime = "27:10.190";
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(lapTime.substring(0, lapTime.indexOf(":")));
    int seconds = Integer.parseInt(lapTime.substring(lapTime.indexOf(":")+1, lapTime.indexOf(".")));
    int milliseconds = Integer.parseInt(lapTime.substring(lapTime.indexOf(".")+1));
    LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.of(0, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

How to gain number of milliseconds of `LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.of(0, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);` ?

Comment: Search for `[java] milliseconds`

Comment: What happens it lap time is an hour or more? I believe your code will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***TL;DR*** Use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html), not [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). See end of answer.

---

#### Question code is incorrect

Be aware that the 4th argument to [`LocalTime.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#of-int-int-int-int-) is **nano**second, not millisecond, which you'd see if you print `localTime`:

```
System.out.println(localTime); // prints: 00:27:10.000000190
```

So you need to change your code to:

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.of(0, minutes, seconds, milliseconds * 1000000);
```

```
System.out.println(localTime); // prints: 00:27:10.190
```

---

#### Using LocalTime

If you wanted the `milliseconds` value back, call [`getLong(TemporalField field)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#getLong-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-) with [`ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#MILLI_OF_SECOND):

```
localTime.getLong(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND) // returns 190
```

To gain *total* number of milliseconds, i.e. not just the `milliseconds` value, use [`ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#MILLI_OF_DAY) as argument:

```
localTime.getLong(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY) // returns 1630190
```

---

#### Using Duration

However, since the input is named `lapTime`, the `LocalTime` class is not the right tool for the job. E.g. your code will fail if minutes >= 60.

The right tool is the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class, e.g.

```
Duration duration = Duration.ofMinutes(minutes).plusSeconds(seconds).plusMillis(milliseconds);
```

Or:

```
Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(seconds, milliseconds * 1000000).plusMinutes(minutes);
```

You can then get the milliseconds directly by calling [`toMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toMillis--):

```
duration.toMillis(); // returns 1630190
```

That works even if the lap time exceeds one hour, e.g.

```
String lapTime = "127:10.190";
. . .
duration.toMillis(); // returns 7630190
```

In Java 9+, you can get the millisecond part back easily, by calling [`toMillisPart()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toMillisPart()):

```
duration.toMillisPart(); // returns 190
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of milliseconds within the second, you can do `localTime.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND)`.

You can do `localTime.toNanoOfDay() / 1000000` to get the number of milliseconds since the start of the day.

Since a `LocalTime` has no day or date associated with it, you can't directly get milliseconds-since-the-epoch.

You can attach a LocalDate to a LocalTime using LocalTime.atDate to get a LocalDateTime. Then you can call atZone, atOffset or toInstant to get an object that can return epochMillis.

Comment: Question says nothing about wanting an *epoch* value. Since input is a "lap time", that wouldn't make any sense anyway. So: -1 for that. --- Other parts of answer is good, though calling `getLong(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY)` would probably be better than `toNanoOfDay() / 1000000`. Anyway: +1 for that. --- So no vote either way from me.

Comment: @Andreas You're giving me a -1 for giving a complete answer ? I'll remember that

Comment: The reason for my virtual down-vote was you entirely ignored an important part of the question, i.e. that the time was a "lap time". A "complete" answer would be to tell OP not to misuse `LocalTime` for a "lap time" value, but use the more appropriate `Duration` class instead, because a lap time *is* a duration, not a time of day.